# Barnes-Hut algoritm insertion center of mass shift

Tags: algorithm, physics, quadtree, orbital-mechanics

I'm having trouble understanding how inserting into a Barnes-Hut quadtree works. If the root represents the center of mass and all of nodes within the quadtree, what happens if you insert something that dramatically moves the center of mass?

For example if you have a quadtree with nodes in the top-right (northeast) and bottom-right (southeast), then insert a super massive object way way down bottom-left (southwest) that shifts the center of mass dramatically in that direction, the aforementioned bottom-left nodes are now in the wrong quadrant. What happens next, will I have to reinsert the nodes that are in the incorrect quadrant or am I missing some logic?

Comment: Why would you insert anything? Masses don't appear spontaneously.

Comment: Barnes-Hut algorithm provides a way to calculate forces on each body in the simulation in O(nlogn) time. I insert an already existing mass into a quadtree to enable this algorithm.

Comment: Seems like you would compute the center of mass first (which takes O(n) time), and then build the tree.

Comment: Computing center of mass occurs when you come by an internal node or turn an external node into an internal one. After all insertions you'll end up with a quadtree where all bodies reside in leaved and all internal nodes are the center of mass of its subtree. I'm just habing trouble deciding what to do when inserting a body that shift the center of mass such that subtrees are in the wrong quadrant. If I reinsert those nodes then it doesn't seem like O(nlogn) time complexity. Unfortunately there's little discussion of this algorithm on the internet and existing implementations don't adress this

Comment: From your question: *"If the root represents the center of mass and all of nodes within the quadtree"* **That's not a requirement. The quadtree just needs to cover the space in which the bodies move.** But if you do want to start with the center of mass at the center of the area covered by the quadtree, then you compute the center of mass first. Then set the size of the first 4 nodes so that the bodies will stay within the area covered by the quadtree. The size of all other nodes is exactly 1/4 of their parent nodes, and their location is completely determined by the location of the parent.

Comment: I'm not following. According to http://arborjs.org/docs/barnes-hut computing the center of mass is always done first and occurs at every internal node until you find an empty leaf. Can you elaborate on what you mean by setting the size if the 4 nodes? I thought that they remain as null until something can be inserted into it and it technically has no size, contrary to how diagrams depict them as recursively divided boxes.

Comment: Are you saying that calculating the center of mass comes after inserting all bodies into the quadtree? I'm getting conflicting explanations of this algorithm where some insert bodies and calculate the center of mass at the sane time while others are insert first, calculate COM second.

Comment: Assuming that the quadtree is exactly how diagrams depict them (as recursively divided boxes), then yes, build the tree first. Then compute the COMs, starting from the leaves.